# How do you install Ack-Grep on Red Hat Linux 6.5?

Tags: rhel, software-installation, ack

I'm not sure how to install ack-grep for redhat linux 6.5. Google only returned results on how to install it for mainly centos and ubuntu only. But what about Redhat? Why isn't there that many users of redhat?

Answer (score 2):

CentOS is Red Hat, more or less, just without the branding and support contract.  Just follow the instructions for that.

As far as why not that many people use Red Hat - it's a commercial distribution geared towards business and enterprise use.  Those sorts of systems have a wildly different use pattern than your run of the mill hobbyist box or dev server, and their admins tend to be experienced.

Installing software on RPM based machines is pretty much all the same - there's a learning curve, but once you learn it you don't really need instructions most of the time.

The package is apparently available in the EPEL repository, which contains packages geared towards Red Hat and CentOS.  Search for "EPEL repo" and find it there.